# use middleware in nextjs to check user is authenticated or not using firebase-auth

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, middleware, next.js13

I am planning to use nextjs 13 in my project with firebase for authentication and database.
My question is how can I use nextjs 13 middleware to check if user is authenticated or not, can i do that, if yes then how?

If not what is the best way to check is user is authenticated and get user data in nextjs from firebase auth. I don't want use "**use-client**" everywhere in my project to get best performance out of it.

By the way i am using app directory in nextjs.